# Как передать значение из cell на другой ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

есть код, который определяет на какую ячейку мы нажали в tableview

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    guard segue.identifier == "segue",
        let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
        let indexPath = MyTakeSum.indexPath(for: cell) else {
            return
    }

    selectedGame = self.items[indexPath.row].name!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    selectedGame = self.items[indexPath.row].name!

    }
```

и есть код, который принимает значение

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)  {
    if segue.identifier == "segue",
        let gamePickerViewController = segue.destination as? twoViewController {
        gamePickerViewController.selectedGame = game!

    }
    print(game)
}
```

После клика на нужную ячейку, я не получаю в консоли печать нужного значения.
Где может быть ошибка в моем коде?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли самое главное:

```
func performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, 
           sender: Any?)
```

Первое: добавим вызов недостающего метода:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    selectedGame = self.items[indexPath.row].name!

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: selectedGame)
}
```

Второе: передадим данные в другой контроллер:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)  {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        if let gamePickerViewController = segue.destination as? twoViewController {
           gamePickerViewController.selectedGame = game!
        }
    }
    print(game)
}
```

**UPD:** Segue должен быть между контроллерами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добрый день, вторую часть кода я должен положить в контроллер который получает данные, верно?

Comment: Нет, она должна быть в передающем данные контроллере

Comment: @SergeyVerigin Ваши три метода замените на мои два

Comment: @Vitaly почему то сначала у меня срабатывает брейкпоинт на GamePickerViewController.selectedGame = game!
а потом только  selectedGame = self.items[indexPath.row].name!
в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Vitaly по итогу получается, что отправляется пустота. Как это исправить?

Comment: @SergeyVerigin Посмотрите что у вас в переменных храниться. Возможно где-то вы ловите nil и естественно получаете ошибку.

Comment: @Vitaly я ловлю nil в случае, если override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)   выполняется раньше чем didSelectRowAt
как этого избежать?

Comment: @SergeyVerigin Значит вы вызываете perform раньше. А как у вас segue в сториборде соединены? Между контроллерами или от view элемента на контроллер?

Comment: @Vitaly от cell в viewcontroller
есть ли программный вариант данного соединения?

Comment: @SergeyVerigin Ну вот и проблема ) Сделайте только между контроллерами а между cell и viewController удалите.

Comment: @Vitaly да, заработало! Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Vitaly у меня есть еще пара вопросов, я могу их задать тут, я думаю, что вы знаете ответы на них, либо могу где то еще написать

Comment: @SergeyVerigin Создайте вопросы в сообществе. Так вы создаете базу знаний. )

Comment: @Vitaly 5 минут :)